# Spring Boot Actuator returning down for applications on Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a running application on Docker. 
But when I try to check its health like server:port/health it says DOWN. 
Why? Is it a common problem with Docker?

Thank you

EDIT:

> 2017-09-27 14:56:30.495  WARN 22559 --- [nio-8234-exec-4] o.s.b.actuate.health.JmsHealthIndicator  : Health check failed
>   javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [vm]
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:333) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:346) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.JmsHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(JmsHealthIndicator.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:81) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.getHealth(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:171) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:145) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [vm]
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:28) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:185) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       ... 75 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/vm
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.loadProperties(FactoryFinder.java:98) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:60) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:148) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:182) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar:5.14.5]
>       ... 77 common frames omitted

Comment: I have personally never experienced such an issue. Can you please provide more information?

Comment: what information would you need?

Comment: check your logs and see why it says down

Comment: @KompiKompi first of all, the app logs - preferably in DEBUG mode

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @KompiKompi, I have a similar issue, did you find the root cause?

Comment: No, I just disabled the healthceck and moved on, but I think this requires some bean with defined transport scheme? Just a wild guess, I did not dig into it more

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't find where and why in my project it tries to connect with **ActiveMQ**, but I managed to disable JMS in health check with
`management.health.jms.enabled=false`